# how to make vectorx replicates 1000 times to get a frame use R

Tags: r

Like `vectorx <- c(10:20)`, to get framex, and the `dim()` of it is `1000*10`

I know how to get the frame by for loop. But is there one function can realize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replicate a vector `vectorx`for 1,000 times , try `matrix`:

```
matrix(vectorx, nrow = 1000, ncol = length(vectorx), byrow = T)
```

---

Note: for you example, the final dim would be 1,000 x 11 as 10:20  has 11 elements.